# Access denied on checkout page for no clear reason

Tags: commerce, users

When I tried to access the cart page I get "Access denied"; this happens with every role, all of which have permission to view the cart/make orders/view orders.

The only thing I can think of is that I have recently moved servers, I don't know how this would effect user permissions though, and every other page is fine.

Any idea what's going on here? Or even a suggestion of how to debug the problem?

Comment: Have these users the permission "Access checkout" granted? Not sure if you are referring to the cart page or the checkout page as you're saying both things

Comment: Yes, these users have "Access checkout" granted, I even tiered enabling all permission for admin to see if that helped but I still get permission denied.

I then tried installing [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminrole) which grants all permissions to admins, and still get access denied.

I can view the cart page on my copy of the site on my old server, maybe something about my new server set-up is causing this, but no other pages get permission denied. Or maybe it's a recent drupal core update or something? I have no idea even how to debug what's going on.

Comment: one time change default theme to bartik or garland. and then check

Comment: Just tried both Bartik and Garland, still access denied.

Comment: It could be many things, the most silly is to make sure that in your new server you don't have a folder called "checkout" in the docroot.

Comment: Debug the function commerce_checkout_access for your order, that'd be where the access is checked.